# Meteor: WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state

Tags: angular-meteor

I don't really know if this is just Meteor of Angular-Meteor, but I receive this error message a lot (in client console). Of course this should be in response to bad code on my part. However I am wondering when should this appear and what situation it tries to describe?

Thanks and bye ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens on auto-refresh of the local meteor server (ie: each time you modify a file).